# type converting C++ std::map into PHP using SWIG

Tags: php, c++, swig

I have a PHP extension that is in C++ and I used SWIG to wrap it. I am trying to create a class that is implemented in C++ as such:

```
Package(const std::map<std::string,std::string> &input_map, const std::queue<std::string> &dates_queue);
```

in PHP by using this script:

```
<?php 
require "prq.php";

$input = array("dataset" => "a050119", "station" => "a050119", "flag" => "1");
$dates = array(1 => "read;chunk;2015-07-01 00:00;2015-07-02 00:00");

$package = new Package($input, $dates); 
?>
```

but I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Type error in argument 1 of new_Package. Expected SWIGTYPE_p_std__mapT_std__string_std__string_t in /home/jlahowetz2/development/package-request-queue/swig/prq.php on line 230
```

which makes sense... I have no clue how to implement a std::map in PHP. I looked at the C++ wrapper that was created by SWIG and found a type conversion for this:

```
static swig_type_info _swigt__p_std__mapT_std__string_std__string_t = {"_p_std__mapT_std__string_std__string_t", "std::map< std::string,std::string > *", 0, 0, (void*)0, 0};
```

My question is: how do I use this type conversion in PHP to pass a std::map to my constructor? Thank you much.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with SWIG but I doubt very much that it will be able to grok any C++ structure of class thrown at it.  I think you're going to have to look into the exact calls available through SWIG to move data across the interface.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
%template(mapStuff) std::map<std::string, std::string>;
```

to the interface file then in PHP treat it like a proxy class.